# Fast Search Crawlers do not appear to be submitting batches to the indexer

Tags: fast-search

We have been trying to debug why our Fast Search Crawls have been slow and during the process we have replaced the self-signed certificates related to the connections to the server. Followed the technet instructions to replace the certificate and then secure the connector on the crawlers. During this process we have seen the following error pop up from SChannel -

> The following fatal alert was generated: 80. The internal error state is 301.

So basically we are completely unable to do any indexing at all in our Farm right now. No real hits with google for that SChannel error except in the cases of virus problems.